# Search for pattern and replace powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I am trying to look through a file and replace any FQDN machine with something generic. this is what i got so far.

```
get-content $location\$file | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace  ".*domain.com" , 'machine.local' }
```

The output is not what i am looking for with this and i am not sure why. its like it cuts off part of the doc all together.
for example, this is my test doc

something something server.domain.com something server2.domain.com something

the the resulting output is

machine.local something
or
something machine.local something.

Please help, this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your regex `.*` is greedy and will grab all characters to the beginning of the line. Change you regex to:

```
\w+\.domain.com
```

This just grabs a word and a period before the domain.com. I am not sure how this will work with the rest of your data as you have only supplied one example.

Answer (score 0):

I see you accepted an answer while I was typing this, but I go into a bit more detail so I'm adding my answer anyway.

Ok, so this is a RegEx issue. Let's start off with what your RegEx means. For this I refer to [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aA1gI1/1), which is an awesome site for testing and troubleshooting Regular Expressions (RegEx). When you use the `-Replace` method as you did it performs a RegEx match by default, and your RegEx breaks down like this:

```
.*
```

The dot (.) character in RegEx will match any character (except New Line, depending on search modifiers). The asterisk causes the previous thing (in this case the dot which matches anything) to repeat that match zero or more times. As it is written it's called a 'greedy' match, and it will match as many times as possible while will fulfilling the terms of the RegEx match.

```
domain
```

This matches the word domain, literally, but is case insensitive.

```
.
```

There's that dot again, and there's no * or + after it, so it's going to literally match any single character.

```
com
```

This matches the word com, case insensitive again.

So we put that all together and we get:

Match everything you can up to the word 'domain', followed by any single character, followed by the word 'com'.

What I think would work better for you is to do this:

```
(GC $file) -replace 'domain\.com', 'machine.local'
```

Unless you are looking to replace the server name as well, in which case I would use:

```
(GC $file) -replace '\S+\.domain\.com', 'machine.local'
```

This uses the `\S` special character which matches any non-whitespace character, so anything except spaces and tabs pretty much. The `+` means that there has to be at least one of those, but it'll match as many as possible. Then we escape the period, because as I mentioned above the dot is a special character in RegEx that matches anything (including spaces!).

This effectively does almost the same thing as Dave Sexton's answer, except mine is a little more flexible since `\w` matches letters, numbers, and a few (very limited) special characters.

So, the updated RegEx101 link for the new match: https://regex101.com/r/aA1gI1/2

I hope you now better understand why you had this issue that you did, and not just have an answer that works, but you don't know why.

Comment: That make sense and regex101 looks like what i needed to figure it out on my own. I was going to follow up with question to see if someone could explain this but after i got this log bundle sent off to the vendor. Thank you for the explanation and the link. i am sure i'll use it in the future when i need to deal with regex.